# Proving a conjugate is a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given a polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}$[x], suppose we have the substitution homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x]$ -> $\mathbb{R}$
where x -> $\sqrt{2}$ and is the identity on constant polynomials. Then we want to find the kernal of $\phi$.

Then any function $f$ with integer coefficients that is divisible by $(x - \sqrt{2})$ is clearly in the kernal when we consider functions over $\mathbb{R}[x]$. However, I believe that the principle ideal generated by $f$ = x$^2 - 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$[x] is the kernel of $\phi$.

However, I'm trying to get the following type of argument to work in order to justify this claim:

Suppose there is a $g$ $\in$  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f$ = $x^2 -2$ does not divide $g$. Then since $f$ is monic, we have that we can use the division algorithm to get the following:

$$fq + r = g$$

Where the degree of $r$ is less than 2, and hence must be $1$ or $0$. If it is degree $1$ there is a linear factor of the form $(x-a)$ for some integer $a$. Is there a way to wrap this up to conclude $f$ must generate the kernel?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You know that $f(\sqrt2)=0$, assume that $g(\sqrt2)=0$ and you have the relation
$$g(x)=q(x)f(x)+r(x),$$ where $r(x)$ is either linear or a constant.

> Plugging in $x=\sqrt2$ what can you tell about $r(\sqrt2)$? Then keep in mind that the coefficients of $r(x)$ are integers and $\sqrt2$ is irrational. Why does this imply that $r(x)=0$?

Comment: r(x) has $\sqrt{2}$ as a root. Hence it is divisible by (x - $\sqrt{2}$). But then it is not degree 0 and must be degree 1 over R. But over Z we have that r(x) cannot be degree 1 as if such a polynomial existed, it would contradict its unique factorization over R, as Z is a subset of R. Then r(x) must be the zero function and so f generates the kernel.

Comment: is that correct?

Comment: Yes. As long as you mention irrationality of $\sqrt2$ :-)

Comment: i think i just need its not an integer, why do u claim we need irrational?

Comment: What if $r(x)=4x-5$ or some such? You are not guaranteed that $r(x)$ would be monic.

Comment: but i know that over R (x - $\sqrt{2}$) will divide it, and being degree 1 or lower, this forces any "extra" factorization to just involve constant terms in R. I suppose some of those coefficients over R could multiply out to remove the $\sqrt{2}$, but that cannot happen using just integers --- that part seems hand wavey

Comment: Polynomial division works over any field (and over an integral domain, if you are dividing by a monic polynomial as is the case here). So, at worst, you can do everything over $\Bbb{Q}$, forget about $\Bbb{R}$. With the coefficients of $r(x)$ known to be rational, AND the fact that it is of degree one, its only zero must be rational. Nothing handwavy about it :-)

Comment: division with remainder can be done when $f$ is monic with coefficients in a ring R( and also a field), which is what we have here with $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. So you doing your division over the rationals and reasoning that since the coefficients must be rational, the root must be rational doesn't seem any different from me saying that over the integers the coefficients are integers and so the roots must be integers. To which you responded with the 4x - 5 comment. Where am i going wrong here?

Comment: The zero of a linear polynomial $ax+b$, that is $x=-b/a$ is not necessarily in the *ring* containing $a$ and $b$. Simply because $a$ need not be a unit of that ring. On the other hand, unless $a$ happens to be zero, division by $a$ is possible in a *field*. That's why we can *only* deduce that the zero of a linear polynomial $ax+b$, $a\neq0$, is in a field containing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: so applying this to our case, we suppose r(x) is some linear term of degree 1. Over $\mathbb{Z}$ we have some linear term, but when we solve for our root it is not guaranteed the root will be in $\mathbb{Z}$, as $a$ is not necessarily a unit as you eluded to. However, over $\mathbb{Q}$, we would have that same r(x) term (as the equation over $\mathbb{Z}$ is still valid over $\mathbb{Q}$) but this time we CAN solve for our root r(x) and we are guaranteed it is a rational number as $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. Hence the root is rational, a contradiction to $\sqrt{2}$ being a root.correct?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$